# 80s sci-fi movie with "tank men"?

Tags: science-fiction, identify-this-movie

I vaguely recall seeing a movie in the 80s (which I assume was made in the 80s) and can't find any information about it.

There were two "tank men" - they had the torsos and heads of men, but with tank treads instead of legs/feet.  Almost like a centaur I guess, but with a tank bottom instead of a horse bottom.

A bit like this "Bonebreaker" Marvel Comics character:  [image]

If memory serves, one was blue and one was red.  There may have been more, but I think these were the two "main" ones.  I think one was good and one was bad.

I think the terrain in the film was fairly rugged - rocks, lakes, etc. - much of the movie took place in nature.

There was also a scene in which an actress (possibly blonde) is wearing a white tank top, and removes it (with her back to the camera), possibly to bathe in a lake.  (Yes, this is what stuck in my ~10 year old mind, unsurprisingly).

Any help identifying the movie?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Eliminators (1986)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliminators) features a half-man, half-tank called Mandroid (real creative huh?).

[image]

> A former pilot rebels against his creator, teaming up with the
>   scientist responsible for android technology, her pet robot Spot, a
>   rough-and-tumble riverboat guide, and a martial arts warrior.

The evil creator eventually converts himself to a cyborg, and his metal parts are red and gold. The scientist is a blonde in a black tank top.

Trailer (looks like the full film is on Youtube too):

Comment: I would *not* want to be the actor wearing those tank tread pants. They look uncomfortable as hell. That scene where the mandroid goes down the stairs had me cringing in emphatic pain.

Comment: Not exactly how I remembered it (I specifically recall the red and blue tank guys), but that must be it.  At 50:50 in the [full video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Db2K6mp7vo) (a little NSFW) is the white tank top part my adolescent mind so distinctly remembers.  Thank you!